# Get return values from <form> tag post method in HTML

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe in my website. I using this HTML code from the documentation.

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key= <mykey>
            data-amount="100"
            data-name="Thank You"
            data-description="Snacks payments"
            data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
            data-locale="en"
            data-zip-code="true">
    </script>
    </form>
```

After fill in the credit card detail, it will return some values. The question from me is how can I get those values?

Comment: What values are you trying to return? The credit card details they type in?

Comment: No, the data after submit the card details. For example stripeToken and stripeEmail.

Comment: That is a legacy way of using Stripe and you should never use it, I'd suggest starting from their current docs. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment